# Quanta Touch doesn't work

Tags: 12.04

Quanta Multitouch screens worked as single input devices from 10.04 LTS all the way up to Ubuntu 11.10. After that, they apparently use some multitouch architecture - but it both doesn't work and breaks single input. Most of the time, the event for letting go of the screen is never captured and this breaks a significant amount of the interface (unity app blocks are dragged around instead of activated, nautilus refuses to acknowledge a click at all - only dragging around files, GTK app buttons are unresponsive etc).

Everything I've read so far has pointed towards a fix being released, but I'm on the latest and updated 12.04.1 and I'm still having these issues. It's a clean install with nothing else on it right now. I tried a bunch of things previously, including compiling a supposedly fixed patched 3.2.0.29 kernel but honestly, I've forgotten most of what I tried and ended up formatting after exhausting my limits of google and patience. Does anybody have any idea what to do from here?

I'm using an Acer T230H which is recognized by lsusb **on 12.04** as

```
hnurseries@pos1:~$ lsusb
...
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0408:3000 Quanta Computer, Inc. Optical dual-touch panel
...

hnurseries@pos1:~$ xinput
Virtual core pointer                            id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                 id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
   ↳ Acer T230H                                 id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
...
```

And **on 10.04** as

```
hnurseries@pos1:~$ lsusb
...
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0408:3000 Quanta Computer, Inc.
...

hnurseries@pos1:~$ xinput
Virtual core pointer                            id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
    ↳ Acer T230H                                id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

The **only** difference is the addition of "Optical dual-touch panel" in lsusb.

Using mtdev-test

```
sudo mtdev-test /dev/input/event4
```

It's clear that the hardware is correctly sending a signal for each finger letting go of the screen (-1) and can accurately track two fingers even when the first one is let go.

I'm more than willing to help debug these issues in any way with someone more qualified but we need to stay on the LTS release if at all possible (these screens are used in a retail environment, we're trying to upgrade before 10.04 is EOL).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if my answer satisfies you: I have a Acer T231H and updated Ubuntu Oneiric, 32 bit:

1. The xorg with all applications works out-of-box with one touch point.
2. Qt4 multitouch demos work out-of-box with 2 fingers.
3. You can get multitouch work somehow with ginn (translates multitouch gestures into keyboard commands+mouse clicks to the applications)

   `sudo apt-get install ginn`

I don't know if ginn is run after restart automatically. At least I had to start it manually after installation:

```
ginn
```

You can tweak the parameters+add more programs:

```
sudo nano /etc/ginn/wishes.xml
```